# NULL Error in Web Dynpro ABAP on CL_NW7_VIEW_ELEMENT_ADAPTER

Tags: abap, webdynpro

My Web Dynpro View generates a short dump at runtime before displaying but after correctly running trough the `WDDOINIT` and `WDDOMODIFYVIEW` methods.

The short dump indicates that "Access via 'NULL' object reference not possible." and occurs several levels deep in standard SAP code in `CL_NW7_VIEW_ELEMENT_ADAPTER=>CREATE_NW7_BY_VIEW_ELEMENT`.

The short dump contains the following search hints:

- "OBJECTS_OBJREF_NOT_ASSIGNED"
- "CL_NW7_VIEW_ELEMENT_ADAPTER===CP"
- "CREATE_NW7_BY_VIEW_ELEMENT"

I've removed embedded views and any logic that might not properly initialise objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can be caused by incorrect use of the [`SPLITTER` layout element](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_06/helpdata/en/fa/2e5023bf794f159440ed207eba2da7/content.htm). While the name might lead you to think that it can be used to seperate flowing elements across lines, it's actually a container element that splits its contents with a draggable separator.

Either **remove the splitter** or add at least one element to it to prevent the null reference exception.

Comment: Second time I managed to do this to myself. :/ Saved as a question for future reference.

Comment: Serial downvoter: care to comment? Answering your own questions is [explicitly encouraged.](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)